# Как предотвратить кэширование страницы php?

Tags: mamp, macos, php, firefox

Я начинающий веб-разработчик и когда делаю изменение в файле `.php`, то не могу сразу получить изменения. Постоянно выводиться предыдущий вариант страницы. Необходимо подождать около 1 минуты для того, чтобы браузер показал результат, уже измененного файла. Перепробовал различные варианты - вставлял код указанный [здесь](http://phpclub.ru/faq/cahcing/WebBrowserCaching), [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site) и [здесь](http://james.cridland.net/code/caching.html). Ничего не помогло.

Использую сервер MAMP. Не знаю может его как-то нужно сконфигурировать?

Comment: а почему именно MAMP?.. есть же классические решения..

Answer (score 2):

Вот так пробовали - http://myrusakov.ru/php-cache.html ?

Comment: это все было в одной из его ссылок.

Comment: Это тоже не помогло.